# Stop printing of generator expression once empty

Tags: python, generator, iterable

I have a fairly basic code that tests both generator functions and generator expressions. It works like a charm, but I can't figure out how to get the generator expression `genPairs` to stop printing once it reaches the final value. I have tried using `for i in range (0, xyz)` for xyz being a number of different len() calls, but I've gotten an error anytime I try to use the size of my generator expression. To save you time, my question is about the final 3 lines of the python code.

Code:

```
import re
def genLetters(string):

    for letter in string:
        yield letter


letterTable = {}
print("Input your string")
regex = re.compile('[^a-zA-Z]')
inStr = input()
newString = regex.sub("",inStr).lower()
test = genLetters(newString)

for i in range(0,len(newString)):
    temp = next(test)
    if temp  not in letterTable:
        letterTable[temp] = 1
    else:
        letterTable[temp] +=1


letterTable = iter(sorted(letterTable.items()))

genPairs = (item for item in letterTable)
while genPairs:
    print(next(genPairs))
```

Output:

```
    Input your string
porkpork
('k', 2)
('o', 2)
('p', 2)
('r', 2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hw2-1.py", line 27, in <module>
    print(next(genPairs))
StopIteration
```

What can I do to get it to not print the `traceback...stop iteration` nonsense? 
Is there a way to limit

Comment: `while genPairs:` will run infinitely because your generator is truthy.

Answer (score 2):

A for loop will exhaust the generator and catch the `StopIteration` for you:

```
for element in genPairs:
    print(element)
```

Using the code `while genPairs` doesn't make sense, because the generator expression itself will always be truthy.

Comment: And that keeps it out of memory still until I want it to be called?

Comment: For the generator itself, yes.  But do note that you already expanded all this data to memory by using `sorted` earlier.

Comment: Dang, good point. I was trying to avoid that so's to actually benefit from the generator expression rather than list comprehension. The problem was I wanted it sorted alphabetically. What might you suggest to sort without expanding the memory?

Comment: @Podo You have at most 26 items, why do you care about memory?

Comment: You can't.  Sorting is an operation that needs access to the entire sequence.

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be a large amount of unnecessary code and generators which don't yield any benefit. I've cleaned it up for you below.

This solution removes the need for iterating generators, and includes [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to perform the counting for you.

```
from collections import Counter
import re

print('Input your string')
regex = re.compile('[^a-zA-Z]')
inStr = input()
newString = regex.sub('', inStr).lower()

letterTable = Counter(newString)

for k in sorted(letterTable):
    print((k, letterTable[k]))
```